# how to add different footer during pdf generation (flyingsaucer/itext)

Tags: java, css, itext, flying-saucer

I have an HTML file which I want to convert into PDF.
I use freemarker template to describe HTML + CSS + custom fonts.
After PDF generation, PDF file contains 10 pages (number of pages is dynamic)
I need to have different footer for the first page, 4th page, and 8th page

for the first page I set footer in following way:

```
@page: first {
   @bottom-center {
       content: element(footer);
   }
}
```

it works
but how to set different footers on 4th and 8th pages? and one more difficulty here that the number of the page where different footer should set can change

I tried to use named page, like:

```
@page different_section: first {
   @bottom-center {
       content: element(footer);
   }
}
#different_section {page:different_section}
```

but this doesn't work.

maybe there is a way how to do it via code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with [CSS3 named pages](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page/#using-named-pages).

The footer is changed for the page containing an element with a specific class or id.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .newpage{page-break-before:always}

        @page {@bottom-center {content: element(footer)}}
        #footer {position: running(footer);}

        @page pagewithspecialfooter {@bottom-center {content: element(specialfooter)}}
        #specialfooter{position: running(specialfooter);}
        .page4and8  {page:pagewithspecialfooter;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">Default footer</div>
<div id="specialfooter">A different footer that appear on page 4 and 8</div>

<div>Page 1 content</div>
<div class="newpage">Page 2 content</div>
<div class="newpage">Page 3 content</div>
<div class="newpage page4and8">Page 4 content</div>
<div class="newpage">Page 5 content</div>
<div class="newpage">Page 6 content</div>
<div class="newpage">Page 7 content</div>
<div class="newpage page4and8">Page 8 content</div>
<div class="newpage">Page 9 content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but in this case, it will create the same footer for pages 4 and up to 7th, but I need to have it only on the 4th page, pages 5,6,7 shouldn't have that footer.

Comment: The specific footer will only appear where the additional class is present. I've updated the example to make the solution a bit more clear.